# How can I change the Seperator option in WordTable? -Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

From the Ruta Documentation, A WORDTABLE is simply a comma-separated file (.csv), which actually uses semicolons for separation of the entries. I need to change the the seperator option.Because Some text contains semicolon, So its coming in seperate column.

I've changed the Seperator Option, I received an error message.

[image]How can I solve this issue.

**Example:**

```
 I really like beef, with mushroom sauce; pasta, with Alfredo sauce; and salad, with French dressing.;0   
 Think before you speak.;1
 We had students from Lima, Peru; Santiago, Chile; and Caracas, Venezuela.;2
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an exception or log before that? The NPE is caused because the wordtable is not available.

Comment: No. I didn't receive such exceptions.

Comment: I just rerun the script. Now I'm not receiving the exception.But by default it taking semicolon as a seperator. Now I need to know how to change the delimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to the current UIMA Ruta version (2.6.1), changing the separator for the csv tables is not supported. Unfortunately, quoting is also not supprted.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Sorry. You could open a feature request.

Comment: Feature becomes available in Ruta 2.6.2. 
See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-5736